# Does anyone know resources for LaTex

Tags: latex

I want to use LaTex to write equations faster and if it is possible to export the result as a png or jpg so that it can be used on a website.

Answer (score 1):

Wikipedia (and its opensource wiki engine) uses LaTeX for that, maybe there are some resources available (at least in the code, as it is opensource).

Answer (score 1):

Your question is very broad.  You could start with [Amazon's List of Latex Books](http://www.amazon.com/gp/bestsellers/books/4185/ref=pd_zg_hrsr_b_1_5_last).

Answer (score 1):

You might want to investigate the StackExchange site [mathoverflow.net](https://mathoverflow.net/) solution - you can read about [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12700/add-latex-support-to-markdown-wmd).  It uses [jsMath](http://www.math.union.edu/~dpvc/jsMath/) which supports [a lot of LaTeX syntax](https://mathoverflow.net/faq#latex).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you already know a little LateX and your primary goal is to get images, a good high-level tool is [mathTeX](http://www.forkosh.dreamhost.com/source_mathtex.html); there are even public servers that will convert to images for you.

If you want to do everything yourself, all the tools use [`dvipng`](http://sourceforge.net/projects/dvipng/) at bottom.

Answer (score 1):

I like both [MathBin.net](http://mathbin.net/7) and [Roger's Online Equation Editor](http://rogercortesi.com/eqn/). The latter lets you control the quality of the output. See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/796890/whats-the-best-way-to-write-mathematical-equations-on-the-web/864730).

Answer (score 0):

try this: http://hausheer.osola.com/latex2png

Answer (score 0):

Here is a small [symbol reference](http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/LaTeX/AoPS_L_GuideSym.php) for LaTeX. If you are looking for something more as a general introduction, you can look at ["The Not So Short Introduction To LaTeX2e"](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/info/lshort/english/lshort.pdf). If you use [Inkscape](http://www.inkscape.org/), there is built in support for rendering LaTeX and there are also extensions that do the same. You can read some commentary about it [here](http://jblevins.org/log/latex/latex-in-inkscape). There are also things like LaTeX to HTML converters; However, at the time I was looking at them, they were somewhat limited in what formulas they could display.

Answer (score 0):

I taught myself LaTeX using [the wikibook](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX). It's fairly comprehensive as an initial guide. I've since bought [The LaTeX Companion](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Latex-Companion-Frank-Mittelbach/dp/0201362996/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&s=books&qid=1266245030&sr=8-1), which is a more advanced guide to in depth typesetting in LaTeX

Answer (score 0):

I use http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/LaTeX/AoPS_L_TeXer.php when I need a quick equation for a web site.

There are packages that will automatically produce images from LaTeX source, but these are often either buggy or used incorrectly.  Many people install them on their blogs, for example, and the images show up if you visit the blog directly but they don't show up if you view the page via a blog reader.  I'm not saying these problems can't be fixed. They can, but it often takes a few tries.

I prefer just to make a gif and stick it in the page. It's low tech and reliable.

One more tip: it's a good idea to put the LaTeX source in the alt tag of the image. This helps people using screen readers.  It helps you too if you need to modify the equation later.

Answer (score 0):

Detextify is a great site that lets you draw a symbol, and it will pop up a list of latex commands that may match your drawing. It's quite accurate! http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html