# Jqmath - apply after page load

Tags: parsing, math, triggers, jqmath

I would like to apply the jqMath script after the initial page load.

The problem I have is that I make an ajax call
which retrieves some jqMath syntax and loads it into a div section of the main page.

However the syntax is not currently being parsed.
How do I ensure jqMath can be triggered when the ajax call returns 
and applied to the appropriate div section ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Call `M.parseMath(myDiv);` after loading `myDiv`.

For example, jqMath automatically does `M.parseMath(document.body);` after the initial page load.

Comment: Look, I'm trying to use [your library](http://mathscribe.com/author/jqmath.html) but I cannot implement it .. May you please help me? Is there any reference on github to explain how can I implement it?

Comment: It's not on github (at least not yet). The main documentation is at http://mathscribe.com/author/jqmath.html. After you read and experiment there, click the "download jqMath" link in the middle of that page and then read the COPY-ME.html file. If you have a specific question after that, post a question to stackoverflow. If you're working on Android, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30263725/how-do-i-install-jqmath-on-android.

Answer (score 2):

The above might fail to work if you use a global variable M for something other than jqMath. The work-around is to call `jqMath.parseMath(element);` for example `jqMath.parseMath(document.body);`