# split a string and wrap substrings in mathml tags

Tags: javascript, arrays, split, mathml

I have a string that I'm trying to split and then wrap with MathML tags. The goal is to have a MathML (possibly MathJax) rendered output for an equation. The problem I'm running into is matching the MathML tags to the different substrings.

For example:

```
str = x + 2;
newStr = str.split(''); //returns [x,+,2]
```

I can loop through the array like so:

```
for (i = 0;i < newStr.length; i++) {
  write('<mn>' + newStr[i] + '</mn>')
```

But this only works for a single MathML tag. How can I map each substring to a tag, wrap it with that tag (preferably referring to the tag in terms of a variable), and then *close* the tag as well (comes into play when using multi-element MathML like `<msup>`).

**UPDATE**

For example, this is what I'm trying to produce:

Input: `x + 2`

Output: `<mi>x</mi><mo>+</mo><mn>2</mn>`

I have been battling this problem all day. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you please give an case example of the input and output you need?

Comment: @amosrivera--please look at the updated post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Libraries like [MathJax](http://www.mathjax.org) and [jqMath](http://mathscribe.com/author/jqmath.html) do this for you, handling numbers, variables, operators, nested parentheses, exponents, matrices, etc.  MathJax supports LaTeX syntax for complicated formatting, where jqMath just implements a simpler unicode-based syntax.  For instance, in jqMath you can do `M.sToMathE('x + 2')` to create a MathML element.  (You could then take its innerHTML I believe if you really wanted it in string form.)  See also [Jqmath - apply after page load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8517334/jqmath-apply-after-page-load).  (Full disclosure:  I wrote jqMath.)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a starting point showing how you can do this kind of conversion into MathML. Note also that it's more pseudo-code than javascript.

```
string str = x + 2
newStr = str.split('');

for (i = 0;i < newStr.length; i++)
{
    string value = Operator_AsMathML(newStr[i]);
    if(value == "")
    {
        if(isdigit(newStr[i][0])
            value = Number_AsMathML(newStr[i]);
        else
            value = Variable_AsMathML(newStr[i]);
    }   
    write(value);
}

string Number_AsMathML(string number)
{
    return "<mn>" + number + "</mn>";
}

string Variable_AsMathML(string varname)
{
    return "<mi>" + varname + "</mi>";
}

string Operator_AsMathML(string opname) const
{
    string front = "<mo>";

    switch(opname[0])
    {
        case '+':
            front += "+";
            break;

        case '-':
           front += "&#x2212;"; 
           break;

        case '*':
           front += "&times;";
           break;

        case '/':
           front += "/";
           break;

        case '±':
           front += "&#x00B1;";
           break;

        default:
           return "";
    }

    front += "</mo>";
    return front;
}
```