# Convert HTML text area value to jqmath formula

Tags: javascript, html, textarea, jqmath

I am new to jqmath; I have contained a textarea field in my HTML:

```
<textarea cols="30" rows="2" id="mathSrc1"></textarea>
```

I will set mathematical formula in the text area so that it will be displayed in `<div>` tag:

```
<div id="mathTgt1"></div>
```

This code is available in http://mathscribe.com/author/jqmath.html. But I don't know how to use it. Please help me.

Thank you.

Comment: Are you asking for a tutorial on how to use jqMath?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i got solution

```
<input type="textarea" name="formula" id="test_formula" onkeyup="paste_formula()" />
<span id="formula_print"></span>
```

script code

```
function paste_formula() {
var val = document.getElementById("test_formula").value;

val = "$$" + val + "$$";
var di = document.getElementById("formula_print");    

di.innerHTML = val;
M.parseMath(di);
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I like Nathan's question - what exactly are you trying to do? The normal case is to have some math in your static web page, which you just surround with $s and it gets parsed and formatted at load time. If you want to create mathematical expressions dynamically (after load time), see [Jqmath - apply after page load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8517334/jqmath-apply-after-page-load). You can also look at the jqmath source to see how http://mathscribe.com/author/jqmath.html does it. All these methods end up calling the same functions to do the actual work (parsing and formatting).