# Need .Net-library to convert math formulas to an image

Tags: .net, html, math, web, formula

I have a website that will need to display some mathematics (mostly fractions and square roots) in HTML. Since MathML does not seem to be supported yet by most browsers, I need a tool to dynamically convert the formulas to transparent images. I've looked into MathML.Net, but I don't need the equation editor, so I was hoping to find something cheaper than $299. Any suggestions?

Comment: How long do you expect to spend looking at this as an issue? How do those hours translate into money? Frankly, if the tool does what you need, I'd think $299 is a bargain here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just do the rendering clientside (javascript), like [math.stackexchange.com](http://math.stackexchange.com) does?  See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1158536/render-math-equations-for-websites-latex) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/796890/whats-the-best-way-to-write-mathematical-equations-on-the-web/864730).

If you *truly* need to render an image on the server, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9071856/238419) - most of those libraries have the ability to export.  I would recommend [MathTex](http://www.forkosh.com/mathtex.html), though it is not native C#.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. It turned out that [jqMath](http://mathscribe.com/author/jqmath.html) was exactly what I needed.