# How to display math equation

Tags: javascript

I have a quiz like this
[image]

The problem is `$x^2$`. I want to make a math equation. `$x^2$` should be `x power 2`. this is the js code

```
const quizdata = [{
  question: "$x^2$ Characterized by skill at understanding and profiting by circumstances",
  options: ["Prescient", "Analyst", "Diminution", "Shrewd"],
  answer: "Shrewd",
  category: 1
}],
```

is there a way to display math equation for this case?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! What have you tried so far to solve this? Where have you failed? You'll normally have more success getting good answers here if you attempt to find a solution yourself, and not ask for a generic "how do I solve this" tutorial

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the best way to write Mathematical Equations on the Web?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/796890/whats-the-best-way-to-write-mathematical-equations-on-the-web)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formatting of your formula looks like TeX. You can either rewrite simple stuff using HTML, e.g.

```
2<sup>2</sup>
```

to achieve 2<sup>2</sup>

Or use tools like https://www.mathjax.org/ for displaying complex math.

Answer (score 1):

Include MathJax lib, for generating nice Latex-based math formulas

```html
<html>
<script id="MathJax-script" async src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mathjax@3/es5/tex-mml-chtml.js"></script>
$$ y=x^2 $$
<html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you have to use HTML tag [`sup`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/sup) for that:

`x<sup>2</sup>` will display x<sup>2</sup>

Answer (score 0):

You can print the math equation the way you want using the ascii math method.

Etc web site.
http://asciimath.org/