# Is there a way to have math formulas look nice on a web page (as in LateX, for instance)

Tags: html, math, formula

I wonder if there is a framework or something else to display Math formula on a web page. Other than using images of those formulas...

Comment: As a possible alternative - is it possible to use e.g. svg, eps or pdf images? - Vector images, IOW, which are less prone to looking ugly.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Math equations on the web](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/775168/math-equations-on-the-web)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check out [MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/), which uses [jsMath](http://www.math.union.edu/~dpvc/jsMath/welcome.html). Looks pretty good, but can take a few seconds to render everything.

Answer (score 7):

You may also check [MathJax](http://www.mathjax.org/), which supports rendering both LaTex and MathML.

Comment: Thank you so much for this. I was sitting here irritatedly thinking "there is no way I need the 1.3Gb LaTeX package just to get some formulas to look right" glad I kept looking.

Answer (score 5):

Check out [this review](http://aiss-007-066.csist.manchester.ac.uk/~stuart/web-maths/index.html) of all of the options for web math display.

MathJax is the best option, but it's still in beta. As far as I can tell though, it's the only solution still under development and it should reach 1.0 soon.

Answer (score 3):

### [Katex](http://khan.github.io/KaTeX/)

A couple of developers from the [Khan Academy](https://www.khanacademy.org/) released a **blazing quick** library based off of Tex called [Katex](http://khan.github.io/KaTeX/):

- Fast
- High-quality
- Self-contained; and,
- Can be rendered on the server

Looks like a great modern option.

[image: Katex sample]

Answer (score 2):

The portable way is to use images.

[MathML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MathML#Web_browsers) really isn't widely adopted.

You can do it with CSS, but again its very different to look right across a wide range of browsers

Here is excellent advice: http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/math/

Answer (score 1):

There is [MathML](http://www.w3.org/TR/MathML/), which some of the newer browsers [support](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MathML#Embedding_MathML_in_XHTML_files). But as a fallback, you will need to use images.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [MathML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MathML), which has both presentation and content flavors.

Answer (score 1):

There's MathML: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MathML

Answer (score 1):

What about [jsMath](http://www.math.union.edu/~dpvc/jsMath/), as used by MathOverflow?

Answer (score 1):

MathJax is the new version of jsMath.  You might want to also check out jqmath at http://mathscribe.com/author/jqmath.html.  I wrote it to be simple, small and fast.

Answer (score 1):

I found this https://github.com/mathjax/mathjax very useful.
It supports:

- AsciiMath
- LaTeX
- Tex
- MathML

Answer (score 0):

MathML should be the standard way to do this, but it's not supported by all browsers. The newest [Google Chart Tools](http://code.google.com/intl/es/apis/chart/docs/gallery/formulas.html) have support for mathematical (TEX) formulas.