# How to insert integration sign along with upper and lower limits using html. Is it possible?

Tags: html

I want to insert an integration sign along with the lower and upper limit. I need its equivalent html code to do this. So what may I do ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to have math formulas look nice on a web page (as in LateX, for instance)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2324718/is-there-a-way-to-have-math-formulas-look-nice-on-a-web-page-as-in-latex-for-i)

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for simple vanilla HTML try this:

```
<span style='font-size:100px;'>&#8747;</span>
<sub style='font-size:40px;vertical-align:-40px;'>a</sub>
<sup style='font-size:40px;vertical-align:60px;'>b</sup>
```

If you're looking for something prettier try @jmbpiano's reference or something like https://github.com/parsegon/math-css