# Simplest Way to Write Math Fractions

Tags: html, mathjax

I currently use MathJax to write math equations because the result looks professional (More [here](http://www.scientificpsychic.com/etc/square-root.html)).  It's like an html language.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML"></script>
```

The problem is that to write one equation requires this much code:

```
 <math display='block'>
<mrow>
<mi>x</mi><mo>=</mo>
  <mfrac>
    <!-- Start Numerator -->
    <mrow><mo>&#x2212;</mo><mi>b</mi><mo>&#x00B1;</mo>
      <msqrt>
        <mrow>
          <msup><mi>b</mi><mn>2</mn></msup><mo>&#x2212;</mo><mn>4</mn>  <mi>a</mi><mi>c</mi>
        </mrow>
      </msqrt>
    </mrow>
    <!-- Start Denominator -->
    <mrow>
      <mn>2</mn><mi>a</mi>
    </mrow>
  </mfrac>
```

Is there a way that I can write math equations like (2y^3)/x^4 and have them appear as neat as MathJax, but with less code?

Comment: Simply save the above as a template in JQuery and plug in values...that would be ideal.

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/775168/math-equations-on-the-web)

Comment: Asciimath is mentioned in the answers that  @R.Schifini 's comment links to, MathJax includes asciimath, cf. http://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/test/sample-asciimath.html for an a example and docs.mathjax.org for more information.

Comment: Note from the future: cdn.mathjax.org is nearing its end-of-life, check https://mathjax.org/cdn-shutting-down for migration tips.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MathJax` supports `TeX` notation that is generally more straightforward. For example, a fraction can be written very simply like this: `a+1\over b+1`.

You just have to set some configurations, that will vary depending on your workflow.

You can see examples here: http://www.tuhh.de/MathJax/test/sample-tex.html

One of the advantage of `MathMl` is that in recent Microsoft Word versions, you can export equation you enter with their equation editor directly to `MathMl`, so the markup is a bit more complex, but if you have Word, you basically have a MathMl editor. To use this, simply go in your Word settings, in Equation section you should have somthing like `copy MathMl to text`. Then you just enter your equations, select, click copy and you can paste it as MathMl.